# Copy Range & Paste to different Sheet 1004 Run-Time Error

Tags: vba, copy-paste

I have tried finding a fix for my problem but what I've tried hasn't worked.
Copying raw exported data to another sheet for sorting and formatting.
Active workbook copy of data to the second sheet, pasting of data error.

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Application-defined or object-defined error

```
Public Sub BOM_FORMAT()

If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count = 1 Then
Sheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count), Count:=3
End If


' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
  NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "RAW"
Columns("C:K").Copy _
Destination:=Sheets(2).Columns(1, 8)

Sheets(2).Select
End Sub
```

Rest of Code is just formatting and works fine.  Error thrown on "Destination" line.

Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the '_Destination' is to keep the '.Copy' reading for parameters

Answer (score 1):

```
Columns("C:K").Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Cells(1, 8)
```

So:

```
Public Sub BOM_FORMAT()

    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count = 1 Then
        Sheets.Add after:=Worksheets(1), Count:=3
    End If

    'number of rows of data
    NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Name = "RAW"
        .Columns("C:K").Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Cells(1, 8)
    End With

    Sheets(2).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: That's fixed it, thanks so very much.
What @Tim had fixed was that I was trying to insert the data into a set of columns but all I really needed to do was indicate the starting cell of that data.